# Getting Exception to Get record by ID using NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am new to Nhibernate, I am trying to get record by ID and I am getting exception

```
Unknown entity class: DAL.Product
```

here is my line of code where I am getting exception..

```
Repository.Get<Product>(id);
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you paste the error description?

Comment: Unknown entity class: DAL.Product

Comment: sorry, haven't read well the post. DAL.Product is a model class? You have a mapping for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about checking if the xml mapping file is marked as "embedded resource"? If the xml is NOT marked as embedded resource you would get an error like that.